# Since RelativeLayeout is not recommended to use in .Net Maui, what techniques would replace it?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui, .net-maui

I used **Factor** of **RelativeLayout** in Xamarin.Forms a lot, this way my app UI scaled properly on any device. RelativeLayout is not recommended for use anymore and no replacement offered, so I wonder what would be techniques to indicate for example I want the xaml element to occupy 80% of it's parent element (container)? Should I calculate real width/height of the container in the runtime, depending on the device resolution? Or there is a better solution? I just can find nothing close in .Net Maui to what RelativeLayout+Factor allowed me to do in Xamarin.Forms.

Answer (score 6):

I fear right now there is no way except Creating your own derivate of a Relative Layout. I've got the same problem of converting a Xamarin App to MAUI. There we did use a relative Layout to display various machines at their respective positions inside a building.

I found a few examples on how to create a custom layout [here](https://github.com/hartez/CustomLayoutExamples/tree/main/CustomLayouts).

I would not recommend using the compatibility namespace. For me it makes problems and upon activating it, some of my page content is no longer displayed.

Hope this helps at least a little.

Answer (score 2):

AbsoluteLayout and RelativeLayout now exist only in the compatibility namespace, you can update your code to use them by adding the new namespace, and prefixing your XAML references:

```
<ContentPage
    xmlns:cmp="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
    ...
    >
    <cmp:AbsoluteLayout>
        <BoxView 
            Color="Red"
            cmp:RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{cmp:ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant=0}"
            cmp:RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{cmp:ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant=0}" />
    </cmp:AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: I understand that, but many sources say it's not recommended, since it's one step before declaring them deprecated. They are left for compatibility sake only, not for new development. I wonder how to develop things like you exampled here without them

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the Grid layout with `ColumnDefinitions="*,8*,*"`.

Place the content in Column 1.